# Pull audience members from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, audience

I need a way to auto-populate an "administrative" audience in SharePoint 2010 from a list of users returned from a database query.  Here's the general setup:

All users are managed in Vision.  Using some SQL wizardry I can pull a list of domain usernames that fit into this "administrative" category.  What I need is a way to have this list pulled into a SharePoint audience that can be recompiled daily to pick up any changes.

I've been searching the internet all morning to no avail.  I've found how to create audiences that use settings from AD, but I see no direct way to pull an audience list from a database.  I'm assuming I'm going to have to write some kind of intermediary extension to manage this, but I have no idea where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure how to auto populate an audience directly. An alternative solution could be to pull all of the users from your database query and insert them into AD via a custom program.  .NET is capable of doing this task.  You could then use the way you found to pull audience members from AD.

Comment: This is essentially what I'll have to do.  Thanks.